# Getting "Cannot use import statement outside a module" even if I have '"type": "module"' in package.json

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I have a simple express backend which I want to test. The backend just returns a messages array when hit `/messages` with a GET.

Note: I understand there could be a simple fix, because I am relatively new to node.js world and have worked mostly in Python environment before. So, please, provide answer with explanation.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6"
  }
}
```

Things to note:

1. `"type": "module"`.
2. I'm using jest and supertest for testing my express enabled backend.

Let's see what my `server.js` looks like:

```
import app from './app.js'

const port = 3000

app.listen(port, () => console.log('app running'))
```

For the purpose of testing, in server.js I only have code to start the server. All the important code is in `app.js`.

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const messages = ['hello', 'hi', 'its working']

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
  res.send(messages)
})

export default app
```

Things to note:

1. `export default app`

Before I proceed to show you my server.test.js, let's see my directory structure.

```
├── app.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── server.js
└── tests
    └── server.test.js

1 directory, 5 files
```

Now, here is my `server.test.js`:

```
import app from '../app'
import supertest from 'supertest'
const requestWithSupertest = supertest(app);


describe('Messages Endpoints', () => {

  it('GET /messages should show all messages', async () => {
    const res = await requestWithSupertest.get('/messages');
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(res.type).toEqual(expect.stringContaining('json'));
    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('messages')
  });

});
```

Thing to note: `import app from '../app'`. I am importing app from the file called app.js which is one directory above in the tree as shown in above `tree` output.

Now that I have everything set up, when I go ahead with invoking the test. I get an error thrown by jest runner. I have removed some output to just show the main error:

```
 FAIL  tests/server.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    [output trimmed...]

    Details:

    /efs/repos/vueandauth/backend/tests/server.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import app from '../app';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.149 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I have searched other question on Stackoverflow, some of them suggest doing a `"type": "module"` in package.json. Which I have already done. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a package.json in the `tests` directory?

Comment: No. I have also posted the tree output of the directory in the question for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jest support on **ECMAScript modules**, you can take a look at this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430)

---

#### In order to transpile the imports you can use Babel ([jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel)).

Install babel:

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

add babel configuration by creating `babel.config.js` or `.babelrc`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
};
```

[working example on GitHub](https://github.com/so-teneff/so-69861340)